ERROR in file_io_posix.cc, trying to locate scaling_cur_freq and scaling_max_freq and couldn't find it
I'm trying to execute a container based on Ubuntu 20.04 and some additional dependencies. It ended up in an error where the project (something external) is looking for files/programs, as shown below.
Error message:
[ERROR file_io_posix.cc:144] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2) 
[ERROR file_io_posix.cc:144] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

I tried looking for the installation of these modules but couldn't find them anywhere. Can someone help me out here? This error will come once I start some of the proprietary Docker containers. I couldn't determine if this is from Docker or the Linux machine I'm working on. I tried looking in other places on the stack overflow, but no solution was available.

I can't say much more than that the official plain ubuntu:20.04 image also lacks the cpufreq directory beneath /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0 when I run it within a VM, but not when I run it on bare metal.  Can we assume that you are running the Docker container on a virtual machine?

This is not a virtual machine. It's a physical one. But are there any options to install them, with some sudo apt-...
